# Is there an MVC Model attribute to disable a field?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a very large View, with several input:hidden and other form controls that **never** need to post back to my model.  I understand that I can disable them (either on the view or in Javascript) and they won't post back, making my request smaller.  It would be nice to put an Attribute on the property of my model indicating it should be disabled?  Did Microsoft provide something like this?  By default, it also generates "The field *field* must be a number" for integer types and "The field *field* is required." for non-nullable types, which bloats my initial Response.

Comment: No, you need to use the attributes overload of the HTML renderer. `@HTML.TextBoxFor(t => t....new {disabled="disabled})`

Comment: `input:hidden and other form controls that never need to post back to my model.` then why are then even on the form to begin with?

Comment: This could include text boxes, check box or radio buttons  that call Java script or hidden elements used by java script.